# Xampp for MAC, Apache can't get started

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I am using MAC OS X 10.8.4

I am using xampp. It was fine for more than 3 months. But today when I start mysql and apache, the mysql got started and apache threw an error as below,

```
Syntax error:

httpd: Syntax error on line 454 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf: No such file or directory
```

I never did any change to any file.

I also tried sudo apachctl stop via terminal, it said unloading error.

Please help me to get my apache start and work again.

::I forgot to say that the "/Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf" file exists::

Fixed:: I changed the path for some configuration file and it's working now, but I didn't know the reason it was working fine for a long time

Comment: Both path seems to be different to me - `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` & `/Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf` .

Comment: Great @swapnesh I never noticed that. Problem solved.